# Update axes on click

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I want to update axes when I clicked on one of them. First, I have the Orthoview3D class where I create the exes, and Orthocanvas, where I create fixes and plot the data .nii. But that three axes are static, and I want to make that dynamic, that are updated in runtime.

```
class Orthoview3D():
    def __init__ (self, fig, data):
        data = np.asanyarray(data)
        xrows, xcols = 2,2
        self._axes = [fig.add_subplot(xrows, xcols, i + 1) for i in range(xrows * xcols)
        fig.set_size_inches((8, 8), forward=True)

class OrthoCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super(Orthoview3D, self).__init__()
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self._figs = set([a.figure for a in self.axes])
        data = load_nii('d_crop_mni_s01_t1w_hires_defaced_MNI.nii')
        data_read = read_img_data(data)
        for fig in self._figs:
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', self._on_scroll)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self._on_mouse)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._on_mouse)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self._on_keypress)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', self._cleanup)   

        ortho = OrthoView3D(fig)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

that's the error: `RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type OrthoCanvas was never called`

Comment: You don't call `super` in `Orthoview3D.__init__`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, `super()` below init of Orthoview3D?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Although, on closer inspection that's not the cause of your error. The line where you call `super` in `OrthoCanvas` should actually be in `Orthoview3D`. You don't need it in `OrthoCanvas` when you later call the `FigureCanvas.__init__`  directly. Have you seen the [PyQt5 embedding example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html)?

Comment: But it throw an `RUnboundLocalError: local variable 'fig' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You probably have a scoping issue. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python
If you are having further problems you should open a new question, as Stack Overflow is not really meant for this kind of back and forth discussion. Also I strongly suggest you write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), both for your own understanding, and to aid others in helping you.